# Requirement for key in std::multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

I have a std::multimap where key is a custom class. Something like this:

```
Class X {
public:
    std::string s;
    int x;
    operator <(const X& other) const { return s < other.s; }
};
std::multimap<X, int> mymap;
```

Now, I'd like to use upper_bound and lower_bound to iterate over all elements with the same value of "s". Do I need to implement some other operator for X (for example: ==). Or it will work properly just like this?

Also, what should I supply as argument for *upper_bound* and *lower_bound*? I assume I should create a dummy object with desired value of "s"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `class X` is the key for the multimap, the parameter to `upper_bound()`/`lower_bound()` needs to be of that type.  If `class X` has an implicit conversion from `std::string` (which is the type of `X::s`) then you can use that as the parameter to `upper_bound()`/`lower_bound()`.

The default comparison for multimap is `less<>` which simply calls `operator <()` - so that's the only operator you a required to have in `class X` for the multimap to work.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to provide an operator == and <.

upper_bound and lower_bound are just like any other find-type method, so you need the same kind of object to compare with - in your case, a 'dummy' object with the required value of s.

**edit**: the comments are correct that you only need operator< for lower/upper_bound, and find. But if you want to call other methods on your container, you will need operator== as well. Eg. if you want to sort() your container, you will need operator==.

The 2 overloads you need for all STL containers are operator< and operator==. I find its best practise to implement them both.

Of course, the question could also be answered more fully by implementing a comparison functor in the map itself, not relying on the objects. This is often a good way to implement different ways of calling find() on the map.

Comment: You do not need to provide an operator ==().

Comment: Second what Mike said. You only need <, not ==.